# How do I address this delegate-controller incompatibility warning?

Tags: iphone, ios

I don't fully understand the warning below.  I believe it has something to do with using the ReaderView delegate and the modal presentation in a TableView controller, but that is a guess on my part.  I tried to rebuild using a View controller with a reusable cell, but continued to get the warning. Below is my code.  Any insights to the issues and suggestions on how to address this warning would be much appreciated?

Compiler says:

> Warning: Assigning to 'id ReaderViewControllerDelegate' from incompatible type 'PdfVPTableViewController *const_strong'

My Code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int row = [indexPath row];
    NSArray * path4 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * path5 = [path4 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path6 = [path5 stringByAppendingPathComponent:_pdfList[row]];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path6]) {

        ReaderDocument *document = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:path6 password:nil];

        if (document != nil)
        {
            ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];
            readerViewController.delegate = self;

            readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

            [self presentViewController:readerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    } else {UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"File Problem, Select Another Photo Page" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];
    }
}

- (void)dismissReaderViewController:(ReaderViewController *)viewController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your `PdfVPTableViewController` class doesn't conform to `ReaderViewControllerDelegate` protocol (hard to say from the code provided). The compiler requires that from the object which is supposed to be assigned to `readerViewController.delegate`. Try to put the delegate in header (or in *.m file within category block) :

```
#import "ReaderViewController.h"
@interface PdfVPTableViewController : UITableViewController <ReaderViewControllerDelegate>
{
    //...
}
@end
```

If you have this already, then perhaps you should add some more code to the question.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I put it in the .h file as you suggested. Worked perfectly.  Thank you!  I'm trying to fully understand this. Could you tell me a little more about what "conforming to a class" fundamentally means?  The xcode vocabulary is still a little foreign to me.

Comment: The protocol is a construction, which describes some methods. To conform to a protocol means for class that this class **has** the implementation for methods, described in protocol (that is it's guaranteed) . So if your protocol has the **required** methods (there are *required* and *optional* ones), and your class doesn't contain the implementation for them, the compiler will give you a warning right away with message that you should implement them. The full understanding will arrive with experience, don't worry ;)  Please, accept the answer if it helped